# Gradle plugin endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin no longer maintained?

Tags: gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

When trying to migrate my Android project from Gradle 7 to 8 I'm stumbling upon this:

> Unable to find method ''void org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.setArchiveName(java.lang.String)''
> 'void org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip.setArchiveName(java.lang.String)'

It turns out that in github https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin has been set to read-only:

> This repository has been archived by the owner on Jan 13, 2023. It is now read-only.

So my question is: how should I proceed with migration to Gradle 8? Are there plans to provide updates to the `endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the plugin's master branch [fixed this 2 years ago](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin/blame/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/tools/gradle/endpoints/framework/server/EndpointsServerPlugin.java#L117-L119), but the fix was never released.

One possible solution is to fork the repo and include it manually as a dependency in your project.

An alternative solution is to reconsider the upgrade to v8 and instead downgrade your project to use the most recent Gradle 7.x.x version. This might also require downgrading some dependencies. I had to downgrade `endpoints-management-control-appengine` and `endpoints-framework-auth` dependencies from `1.0.14` to `1.0.11`.

Comment: I considered forking the repo but decided to not follow this path since it adds (unwanted) complexity to my solution. Also, I would now have to support my own fork for all oncoming changes which would further distract me from working on the core application.

Down-grading Gradle would not solve the issue in the long run since Android Studio likes Gradle 8 too much ;)